# ArrayList - how do I change a certain element in an entry of the ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm new to the ArrayList model.

I have an ArrayList which has several elements (d1 and d2 in the code below) and several entries.

I've seen the method set which takes the entry number and the new value. But how do I manage which element to modify.

In the example below how do I do if I want to modify d2 in the 4th entry of the ArrayList?

```
    private ALdata ldata;
    private ArrayList<ALdata> aLdataArrayList;
    public class ALdata {
        String d1;
        String d2;
    }

    public ArrayList<ALdata> addData(){
        aLdataArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        ldata = new ALdata();
        ldata.d1 = "data 1";
        ldata.d2 = "data 2";
        aLdataArrayList.add(ldata);
        return aLdataArrayList;
    }
```

Comment: use the `get(3)` method on the list, or not? I don't see the problem here

Comment: use `aLdataArrayList.get(3).setD2("Modify here")`.

Comment: `how do I manage which element to modify.` by it's index (which you called `the entry number`)

Comment: I use the get to retrieve the value, but how do I do to update the value. I would need a method like set(4,"new value", in_d2) ?

Comment: @Abhay so I need simply to add a setter in my code: setD2 ?

Comment: yes You need to add getter and setters.

Comment: ok. thanks. I made a comment to Ionut below that I thought that when you do aLdataArrayList.add(ldata) the system would copy internally in a new memory structure? I am wrong?

Comment: I don't get what you're aksing. `get(3)` is used to get the 4th element from the list. On this element indeed you have to call the appropriate setter method. That's just how Java works

Comment: @AKSW: it's clear now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`aLdataArrayList.get(3).getALdata().setd1("your new string");` 
Of course you need setters & getters for every field in this class

Comment: I was under the assumption that when you do aLdataArrayList.add(ldata) the system would copy internally in a new memory structure? I am wrong?

Comment: @narb, yes you are wrong. It will return you the reference to the item in the list, not copy it to new memory cell

Comment: Ionut gets the points but thanks to all: Abhay, Vladyslav and Ionut.